# How can i render A modal in my Api servises?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-router

Hello i'm trying to show a modal everytime when my api response with a error can you help me ? how can i do it ? i'm using react hooks

```
const restService = (path, responseType = 'json') => {
  const apiUrl = `${CONFIG.API_HOST}/${path}`;


  const create = async (body) => {
    const config = {
      responseType
    };

    try {
      const response = await axios.post(apiUrl, body, config);

      
      return response.data;
    } catch (errors) {

      //show modal

      return {errors};
    }
  };

  return {
    find,
    create,
    update,
    remove
  };
};
```

Modal and settings to active the modal

[Modal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rdpp7.png)

[settings if modal is showing or not](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P9Jbw.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by using [React's Conditional Rendering](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html).

Here's an example on how to achieve this: https://dev.to/kevhines/triggering-an-error-modal-in-react-3pm9

The component for the error message in the end of the article looks something like this:

```js
import React from "react";
import {connect} from 'react-redux'
import clearError from '../actions/clearError'

class ErrorModal extends React.Component {

    state = {
      show: false
    };


    onClick = (e) => {
        this.setState({
          show: false
        });
        this.props.clearError()
      };

      componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
        if (this.props.error && !prevProps.error) {
          this.setState({
            show: true
          });
        }

    }

    render() {
        if(!this.state.show){
            return null;
        }
      return <div className="modal" id="modal">
                <div>
                    <a href="#close" title="Close" className="close" onClick={this.onClick}>X</a>
                    <h2>Error Message</h2>
                    <p>{this.props.error}</p>
                </div>
            </div>
    }
  }

  function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {error: state.error}
  }

  export default connect(mapStateToProps, {clearError})(ErrorModal)
```